# Eclipse add comment lines in non c++ headers/source files

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse20 for C++ projects. In the configuration files ending with `.cfg`, the method to add block comments, like ctrl+/, doesn't work for these kind of files. How can I use the same shortcut keys for non C++ header/source files?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use the `#` operator to make a comment in cfg files. `# This is a comment`

Comment: cfg file needs to use // for comment